# Regex - match arguments of function signature

Tags: regex

I need a regex matching argument names and their types of function signature, eg. for the following signature

```
void f(const type1& arg1, type2 arg2, type3* const arg3);
```

I would expect to get:

- const type1&
- arg1
- type2
- arg2
- type3* const
- arg3

Is this possible? I have tried with

```
(\w+)\s(\w+)\((([\w\*\&\s]*)\,?)*\)\;
```

but for some reason this is not working.

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of AST parser, rather than regex.

Comment: [We are not supposed to link to the zalgo regex answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261561/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant) but it applies here too.

Comment: Is your goal to match a format of this example only? What tool or language are you using?

Comment: @Thefourthbird no, this is just one example, what I need to match are argument names and types, language and tools doesn't really matter when it comes to regex

Comment: @qerigan There are a lot of different [regex engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) and do not all support the same functionality.

Comment: @qerigan The programming language and version matters big time. Regex is not identical across all programming languages. Some languages implement a specific subset of regex and others are completely missing features such as lookarounds.

Comment: I know but that is really not relevant to me, you can use any engine you like if you know the answer that is...

Comment: I think writing a parser would be a better option. A pattern like this could match the current example but it can be error prone https://regex101.com/r/eSNWDq/1/

Comment: @qerigan no, you *can't* use any engine you like. Since engines support different features of regex, you *can* have something that matches in one but doesn't in another. Also, regex engines are *generally* very bad at the task you're trying to solve with them here. I think there might be an implementation or two that might be able to solve this problem but in general, this is not solvable via a single regex engine, as you can't have indefinitely repeated capture groups and *extract* those captures. You'll only get the last one. In programming languages, you can match one at a time in a loop.

Comment: fine let's just say I will use pcre... now are you able to answer the actual question? btw I didn't ask if regex is the best way to do it...

Comment: What if it's *impossible* to do in regex?

Comment: @VLAZ that is fine as well